# SQLite dando erro "near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1):"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, sqlite3

Alguém sabe o que está de errado para estar dando esse erro?

```
I/System.out: ERRO 1 :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tbcliente (  IdCliente int(11) NOT NULL,  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL,  TipoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  NomeCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CPFCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CNPJCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  IECliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  EmailCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  TelCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CEPCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  RuaCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  NoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  BairroCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CompCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CidadeCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  EstadoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  AtivoCliente int(1) DEFAULT NULL,  DataCliente date DEFAULT NULL,  HoraCliente time DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdCliente,IdEmpresa)) CREATE TABLE tbempresa (  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  RazSocEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  FantaEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CNPJEmpresa varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,  IEEmpresa varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  TelEmpresa varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,  LogrEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  BairroEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  NumEmpresa varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,  ComplementoEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  MunEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  CodMunEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  UFEmpresa varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,  CepEmpresa varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,  EmailEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  AtivoEmpresa int(1) DEFAULT NULL,  CrtEmpresa int(1) DEFAULT NULL,  UltProdEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  UltNotaEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  UltClienteEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  UltUsuarioEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  UltGruEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdEmpresa))
     CREATE TABLE tbformas_de_pagamento (  IdFormaPagamento int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  NomeFormaPagamento varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  TipoFormaPagamento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdFormaPagamento))
     CREATE TABLE tbncm (  NCM double DEFAULT NULL,  DescNCM varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,  AliqNacNCM double DEFAULT NULL,  AliqImpNCM double DEFAULT NULL,  AliqEstNCM double DEFAULT NULL,  AliqMunNCM double DEFAULT NULL,  AtuNCM varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,  ChaveNCM varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL)
     CREATE TABLE tbproduto (  IdProduto int(11) NOT NULL,  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL,  IdGrupo int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  DescProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  UmProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  IcmProduto float(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,  NacProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  CFOPProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  CsosnProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  PrcVisProduto float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,  PrcPrzProduto float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,  NCMProduto varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,  CESTProduto varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,  GTINProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdProduto,IdEmpresa))
     CREATE TABLE tbusuario (  IdUsuario int(11) NOT NULL,  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL,  NomeUsuario varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  SenhaUsuario varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  NivelUsuario int(4) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (IdUsuario,IdEmpresa))
```

Segue todo a classe banco a baixo:

```
package com.example.gabriel.agilmobile.Banco;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public CriaBanco(Context context){
        super(context, "AgilApp", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE tbcliente (" +
                "  IdCliente int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  TipoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NomeCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CPFCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CNPJCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  IECliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  EmailCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  TelCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CEPCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  RuaCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  BairroCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CompCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CidadeCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  EstadoCliente varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AtivoCliente int(1) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  DataCliente date DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  HoraCliente time DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (IdCliente,IdEmpresa)" +
                ") CREATE TABLE tbempresa (" +
                "  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                "  RazSocEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  FantaEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CNPJEmpresa varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  IEEmpresa varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  TelEmpresa varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  LogrEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  BairroEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NumEmpresa varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  ComplementoEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  MunEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CodMunEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UFEmpresa varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CepEmpresa varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  EmailEmpresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AtivoEmpresa int(1) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CrtEmpresa int(1) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UltProdEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UltNotaEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UltClienteEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UltUsuarioEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UltGruEmpresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (IdEmpresa)" +
                ")\n CREATE TABLE tbformas_de_pagamento (" +
                "  IdFormaPagamento int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                "  NomeFormaPagamento varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  TipoFormaPagamento int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (IdFormaPagamento)" +
                ")\n CREATE TABLE tbncm (" +
                "  NCM double DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  DescNCM varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AliqNacNCM double DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AliqImpNCM double DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AliqEstNCM double DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AliqMunNCM double DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  AtuNCM varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  ChaveNCM varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL" +
                ")\n CREATE TABLE tbproduto (" +
                "  IdProduto int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  IdGrupo int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  DescProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  UmProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  IcmProduto float(3,2) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NacProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CFOPProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CsosnProduto int(11) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PrcVisProduto float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PrcPrzProduto float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NCMProduto varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  CESTProduto varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  GTINProduto varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (IdProduto,IdEmpresa)" +
                ")\n CREATE TABLE tbusuario (" +
                "  IdUsuario int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  IdEmpresa int(11) NOT NULL," +
                "  NomeUsuario varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  SenhaUsuario varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  NivelUsuario int(4) DEFAULT NULL," +
                "  PRIMARY KEY (IdUsuario,IdEmpresa)" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        System.out.println("Opa! já foi né?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente colocar um ponto e  virgula ";" antes de cada CREATE TABLE